# Implementation of filling (Colour)

Tags: plotting, filling

I have a question. When I use "Filling"

```
Plot[Evaluate[{x^2, x}], {x, 1, 2}, PlotRange -> All,  Filling -> {1 -> {2}}]
```

One of the functions appears in orange and the other one in blue, there is some way to make that both appear in the same color?

I read the documentation but I can't find a way to do this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think what you want is:

```
Plot[{x^2, x}, 
    {x, 1, 2},
    PlotRange -> All,
    Filling -> {1 -> {2}},
    PlotStyle->{Blue, Blue}
]
```

Comment: You can simplify the option to `PlotStyle -> Blue`

Comment: Also note that `Evaluate` does nothing here.